# USB based mouse too slow in my dell laptop

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have a Windows 7 32 bit Dell laptop with a touch pad that works perfectly fine.

I connect a USB mouse and find that it freezes at times (infact most times). I go into the control panel and look at mouse pointer speed and make it the "Fastest".

That does not seem to solve my problem though. Does anyone have any suggestions? Is it because the mouse is too old?

Comment: Does it work on another computer? Or is it just broken?

Comment: It's probably just broken. Increasing pointer speed would help if it was too slow, not if it stops moving from time to time.

Comment: You might have a driver problem try to find the mouse in the devices then remove the driver or rollback see if that helps

Comment: Are there any genuine reasons as to why this question is downvoted? @SBI I have only tested with two computers but both are windows 7 32 bit laptops. I will try the device driver solution

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the driver for the mouse.  I've had issues on machines with USB mice that used an out of date driver and had all sorts of problems, such as the cursor jumping around the screen, random slowdowns, etc.