# USB mouse incredibly slow on brand new laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, performance, mouse

Just purchased a Dell Latitude E6540 with a ~16" screen (Windows 7). The mouse is terribly slow, even after adjusting it in Mouse Properties (Pointer Options -> Motion -> Fastest). To move the mouse from one corner of the screen to the opposite takes 2 or 3 long strokes of the hand (*roll - lift - roll - lift - roll*). At this rate I'm going to get Carpal Tunnel in about a week.
Is there any other advanced technique to speed up the mouse (a registry setting, perhaps, that might increase some "multiplier" on the speed setting)?

I've tried two different mice (both cheap Dell models) with the same results. The mice themselves work fine on other machines.

(The touchpad, on the other hand is lightning fast; but I'm not a touchpad guy. Interestingly, there is a touchpad settings interface that is separate from the mouse settings; but if I reset the touchpad speed to a comfortable setting, the mouse slows to an even worse crawl -- barely moves.)

Would you suggest upgrading my mouse to a more expensive model? Might it come with a dedicated driver and independent speed settings?

(NOTE: Based on the suggestions on [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/611732/usb-based-mouse-too-slow-in-my-dell-laptop), I checked the mouse driver and confirmed that it is using the same Driver version as my other two computers (laptop & workstation): 6.1.7600.16385 (6/1/2006). Since the mice works fine on those machines, I assume the driver is not the problem. (Unfortunately, I need administrative privileges to confirm that conclusion, which I don't have.)

**UPDATE:** I just borrowed a friend's fancy Logitech mouse and it worked great. So apparently an upgrade is in order. It's wierd that the mouse that came with the laptop is so pokey.

Comment: I doubt that spending more money on a more expensive mouse will help.

Comment: Double check the Hardware tab - are you sure you're adjusting the settings for the mouse, and not the touchpad?

Comment: @BenPlont: yes, definitely. I have triple checked.

Comment: I'd try to upgrade the mouse driver.  A driver from 2006 is pretty old.